# Store function returns(derived values) in Graphite

Tags: graphite

Is it possible to store them as new keys? 
E.g. I want to calculate
highestAverage(divideSeries(total_request_processing_time.*,total_request_count.*),3) 
while default Graphite syntax won't allow such combination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you want the division to be interleaved. As in `divideSeries(A.*,B.*)` should become- `divideSeries(A.1,B.1), divideSeries(A.2,B.2)...` and so on.

No. This is not straightforward because metrics with wildcards are returned as a `seriesList`.
Quoting the docs-

> **Series List:**
>
> A series name or wildcard which matches one or more series. Series
>   lists are received by functions as a list of matching series. From a
>   user perspective, a series list is merely the name of a metric. For
>   example, each of these would be considered a single series list:
>
> ```
>    metro_east.servers.apache02.system.load_average.1_min,
>    metro_east.servers.apache0{1,2,3}.system.load_average.1_min
>    metro_east.servers.apache01.system.load_average.*
> ```

So `divideSeries(A.*,B.*)` is resolved as `divideSeries(A.1,A.2,B.1,B.2)`, which, is invalid as this function accepts only two series at a time.

What you *can do* is make a script that prepares the interleaved division-ready API calls.